# WEB API Sequence contains no elements

Tags: c#, linq, asp.net-web-api2

I have created a `WEB API` which is working on my local system. But after deploying it on the server it gives me bellow error/exception.

> {"Message":"An error has occurred.","ExceptionMessage":"Sequence
>   contains no
>   elements","ExceptionType":"System.InvalidOperationException","StackTrace":"
>   at System.Linq.Enumerable.First[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n at
>   System.Linq.Queryable.First[TSource](IQueryable`1 source)\r\n at
>   ActualWebService.Controllers.MetersController.GetByMsn(String msn,
>   DateTime dt)"}

**I am checking it on postman in server and also in my local system**

Below is my code

```
 public HttpResponseMessage GetByMsn(string msn, DateTime dt)
    {          
        try
        {

            var result = medEntitites.tj_xhqd.Where(m => m.zdjh == msn)
                                             .OrderByDescending(o => o.sjsj)
                                             .Select(s => s.sjsj)
                                             .First();

            DateTime resulted = new DateTime();
            DateTime userSent = new DateTime();

            resulted = Convert.ToDateTime(result);
            userSent = Convert.ToDateTime(dt);


            double diff = Math.Abs((resulted - userSent).TotalMinutes); // here i am checking the difference between the user sent datetime and resulted date time

            if (diff <=10)
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { data = new { Response = "Yes"} });
            }
            else
            {
                return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, new { data = new { Response = "No" } });
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
        }
    }
```

**WebApiConfig**

```
 config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
       name: "GetByMsn",
       routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}/{msn}/{dt}",
       defaults: null,
       constraints: new { msn = @"^[0-9]+$" , dt = @"^\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}$" }
       );
```

**SERVER LOCAL URL:** `http://localhost:8080/api/meters/GetByMsn/0002999000536/2017-10-21T18:26:08`

I don't know why this API is not working `LIVE` as it's working on local system. It should work on server also.

Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `First()` extension method will throw an exception when the source sequence is empty.  In this case, it looks like your LINQ expression with that where clause is not returning a valid collection, hence you are getting this error.

You should use `FirstOrDefault()` and check whether it is null or not before proceeding.

```
var result = medEntitites.tj_xhqd.Where(m => m.zdjh == msn)
                                             .OrderByDescending(o => o.sjsj)
                                             .Select(s => s.sjsj)
                                             .FirstOrDefault();
if(result==null)
{
  return Request.CreateErrorResponse(HttpStatusCode.NotFound, ex);
}
```

`FirstOrDefault()` method returns the first element of a sequence that satisfies the condition or a default value if no such element is found. You will get `null` if there are no records matching your condition.

Comment: Just for your advice, is it a good practice to catch this InvalidOperationException instead of checking the result?

Comment: Exceptions should not be used for control flow. So i would not do that in this case.